# How to open .img file in Windows/Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, kali-linux

I'm trying a level about forensics on a forum. I have a .img file which I've been trying to recover. In windows i tried 4 tools,but only one sort of worked and I can t open any of the files. I analysed the file with trid and I got back that is: `40.2% .ATN, 16,1%.WK` etc(I don't know if it helps).I also installed linux and ran `fdisk -l forensics1.img` and I get

```
fdisk -l forensics1.img

Disk forensics1.img: 25 MiB, 26214400 bytes, 51200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Could someone give me any ideas about how to open the file ?

Edit: When  I run `dd if=forensics1.img | file -`  I get 
`/dev/stdin: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=3252234c-f5e0-4ed4-a809-beb029819989, volume name "Forensics" (extents) (huge files)`

Comment: By what software this image built? Possibly it not linux generated image?

Answer (score 3):

There is actually no difference between `.iso` and `.img`.
Copy it to a `*.iso`:

```
sudo cp forensics.img forensics.iso
```

And try to mount:

```
sudo mkdir /media/iso
sudo mount -o loop filename.iso /media/iso
```

Copy it for backup in the case it is really something different.

Comment: Tried that but when I click on the mounted folder it s empty

Comment: See my edit. Maybe it helps figuring out how to open it.

Answer (score -2):

Use poweriso or daemontools on windows to mount it.

Comment: It doesn't work with those. I tried. I think it has to be a forensics tool, but I haven't found the right one ..

Comment: @BogdanDaniel Perhaps edit your question to include the tools you've tried already, and what the results were.  Otherwise this is probably just going to devolve into just a list of "name every tool that can mount an img/iso". ;)

Answer (score -2):

Try Win32DiskImager to burn it to a disc which can then be used in the PC. Failing that, see if you can find a tool to convert it to an ISO which in my experience seems to be supported a lot more.